# How to solve mysql server 5.5 update dependency issue?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, dependencies, mysql5.5, packages

since a month or two i cannot update package on my ubuntu server. The problem concern the mysql package which seems newer on the server that the minimum required ??  :

```
lm@s8:~# sudo apt-get upgrade -f
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
Correction des dépendances... Fait
Les paquets suivants seront mis à jour :
  mysql-server mysql-server-5.5
2 mis à jour, 0 nouvellement installés, 0 à enlever et 0 non mis à jour.
2 partiellement installés ou enlevés.
Il est nécessaire de prendre 0 o/8 842 ko dans les archives.
Après cette opération, 14,3 ko d'espace disque supplémentaires seront utilisés.
Souhaitez-vous continuer [O/n] ?
dpkg : des problèmes de dépendances empêchent la configuration de mysql-server-5.5 :
 mysql-server-5.5 dépend de mysql-server-core-5.5 (= 5.5.24-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) ; cependant :
  La version de mysql-server-core-5.5 sur le système est 5.5.28-0ubuntu0.12.04.3.
```

can anybody tell me how to clean this with the minimum sql interruption please ?Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

solved by running `sudo aptitude install -f`